# I want to make a Countdown Stopwatch

Tags: javascript, html, countdown, stopwatch

I want to make a countdown Stop watch in which I can define time and it reduce to 0:00 in which I am having 3 button i.e Start, Stop, Reset.

Can anyone help I Searched many website's but did't get the thing I want.

Comment: Did you try something? Your own ideas?

Comment: same like this https://jsfiddle.net/MUn4k/54/ but not in angularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this hope work for you

```js
var CCOUNT;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnct').click(function () {
        CCOUNT = $('#seconds').val();
        cdreset();
    });
});
var t, count;

function cddisplay() {
    document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;
}

function countdown() {
    // starts countdown
    cddisplay();
    if (count === 0) {
        // time is up
    } else {
        count--;
        t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }
}

function cdpause() {
    // pauses countdown
    clearTimeout(t);
}

function cdreset() {
    // resets countdown
    cdpause();
    count = CCOUNT;
    cddisplay();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="frm">Seconds:
    <input type="text" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="0" size="2" maxlength="2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnct" value="Input" />
</form>
<span id="timespan"></span>

<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="countdown()">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="cdpause()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="cdreset()">
```

Comment: Thanks Just wanted This thing :)

Answer (score 1):

> First you should try it yourself.

If you fail to do that i think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDnfrlK2CLg) video will help you to build a stopwatch. 
Or you can see [this](http://knowpapa.com/js-stopwatch/) blog post.
and [here](https://gist.github.com/electricg/4372563) is a another example of stopwatch.